# How to remove error to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()'on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have the following activities.

1. User_info: In which I have edit text boxes to obtain user data from SQlite and allow user to change his data.
2. User_confirmation: If a user wished to modify his personal information he needs to go to the activity User_info, but before going he has to re-enter his email and password.

This is a function in DBHelper Class to send data to user_info.

```
public Cursor getAllData(String email, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res=null;
        if ( res.moveToFirst())

            res = db.rawQuery("Select * from persons where email = ? and password = ?", new String[]{email, password});
            return res;

    }
}
```

I am getting this error.

```
2021-06-15 15:18:52.264 26638-26638/nanodevlab.screens E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nanodevlab.screens, PID: 26638
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nanodevlab.screens/nanodevlab.screens.userconfirmation}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
        at nanodevlab.screens.DBHelper.getAllData(DBHelper.java:80)
        at nanodevlab.screens.userconfirmation.onCreate(userconfirmation.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
2021-06-15 15:18:52.355 26638-26643/nanodevlab.screens I/zygote: JIT allocated 56KB for compiled code of void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
```

This is how I am calling the getAllData() function.

```
Cursor c=DB.getAllData(emailid,pass);

        int index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("username");
        String firstName = c.getString(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the method `getAllData()` you set `res` to `null` and then you try to `moveToFirst()` which throws the error.
There is no need for `moveToFirst()` because the purpose of `getAllData()` is to return the cursor and not iterate over it.
Your code can be simplified to:

```
public Cursor getAllData(String email, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("Select * from persons where email = ? and password = ?", new String[]{email, password});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But it is not working for me. It says      Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: @Hamna the error you get is not thrown from the code in my answer. It is thrown when after the call to `getAllData()`. Debug your code to check which line throws the error.

Comment: String firstName = c.getString(index);, this one

Comment: Cursor c=DB.getAllData(emailid,pass);
                int index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("username");
                String firstName = c.getString(index);

                index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("email");
                String email = c.getString(index);

                index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("countrycode");
                String countrycode = c.getString(index);

Comment: @Hamna first check the value of the variable `index` and if it is not >= 0 this means that there is no column `username` in the table. If it is >=0 then probably there the cursor does not contain any rows because there is no row with that email and password that you used to run the query.

Comment: @Hamna this is where you should use moveToFirst(): `if (c.moveToFirst()) { int index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("username"); String firstName = c.getString(index); index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("email"); String email = c.getString(index); index = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("countrycode"); String countrycode = c.getString(index);}`